# Alternative to pragmarx/zipcode package in laravel

Tags: laravel, package

So, I have a project of Laravel 6 and i have to update it to the Laravel 9. I can't find the alternative to pragmarx/zipcode package.

There are different packages involved, i found upgraded version or found something to replace it by some other package but this package pragmarx/zipcode needs guzzle 4, 5 or 6 but later version of PHP and Laravel needs higher guzzle so, Is there any alternative to this pragmarx/zipcode package I can use?

Comment: you can fork the project from `antonioribeiro/zipcode` and try to upgrade it to work with guzzle newer version since this project is deprecated (last commit was 2019).